# How to write if statement for "post don't have featured image"

Tags: wordpress

How can I say to Wordpress to insert something if post does NOT have featured image. I can not use if-else. I need to use only if, so if "post don't have featured image" and then I'll add what to do.

I was thinking something like:

```
<?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail(' false '))  ) { ?>
```

but above is not working...

Above code will go into loop, in a specific page.

Please note I am total noob and not a coder neither, so please give me detailed explanation how to do something. Thanks a LOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a non coder, you were pretty hot on the trail.  Assuming you are in [THE LOOP](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) you can use :

```
<php if(!has_post_thumbnail()){ 
     //Your stuff here
}?>
```

If you are NOT in [THE LOOP](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), you just need to pass the post's ID

```
<php if(!has_post_thumbnail($post_id)){ 
     //Your stuff here
}?>
```

The ! symbol is for "not" which says if the post does not have a post thumbnail.